# Python wont choose between 2 if options

Tags: python, if-statement

I am coding a python tic tac toe program. I have put two 'if' functions for it to choose from and it chooses from user input. But my problem is that python runs both choices. (BTW I imported sys)

Heres the code:

```
                            if move3 == ('4') or ('4.)') or ('four') or ('Four'):
                                    print ('|O|O|X|')
                                    print ('-------')
                                    print ('|O|X|6|')
                                    print ('-------')
                                    print ('|X|8|9|')
                                    print ('I win')
                                    sys.exit

                            if move3 == ('7') or ('7.)') or ('Seven') or ('seven'):
                                    print ('|0|0|X|')
                                    print ('-------')
                                    print ('|X|X|6|')
                                    print ('-------')
                                    print ('|O|8|9|')
                                    move4 = input()
                                    if move4 == ('6') or ('6.)') or ('six') or ('Six'):
                                            print ('|O|O|X|')
                                            print ('-------')
                                            print ('|X|X|O|')
                                            print ('-------')
                                            print ('|O|X|9|')
                                            print ('Draw')
                                            sys.exit
```

Comment: You need to rewrite whole expression for every or

Comment: Im not sure if this is it but maybe sys.exit is function and you should be using sys.exit()?

Comment: Sure, you could fix the bad python posted in this code, or you could use "in" rather than "or", but wouldn't it be better to handle all the IO separately from the game logic? Don't validate your input in the middle of executing game moves.